# cl::Event::waitForEvents returns -7 (CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_ FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST)

Tags: c++, events, opencl

I am attempting to run the same kernel on two GPU devices concurrently within the same context.

I have hit a snag, where when trying to profile the event object, I get a -7 (event object not available) for the second command queue.

When I wait for events then it errors out with -7. This only seems to happen in command queue 2.

Any idea why? Any help would be much apprecated.

Code attached.

```
void *bytes;
float *zeropad;
float *output_f;

void *outputbytes;
int ret;

ret = posix_memalign(&bytes, total_alignment_requirement, cshape[level][1]*(size+2)*(size+2)*sizeof(float));
zeropad = (float *)bytes;


//float *output_f = (float *)calloc(cshape[level][0]*size*size,sizeof(float));  

//SR assigning aligned memory
ret = posix_memalign(&outputbytes, total_alignment_requirement, cshape[level][1]*(size+2)*(size+2)*sizeof(float));
output_f = (float *)outputbytes;

unsigned int total=0;

//prepare matrix for OpenCL    
padding_input(matrix,zeropad,size,in_depth);

cl::Buffer zeropad_buf(openclObjects.context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,(size+2)*(size+2)*cshape[level][1]*sizeof(float),zeropad);

cl::Buffer output_buf(openclObjects.context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR  ,cshape[level][0]*size*size*sizeof(float),output_f);
cl::Buffer bs(openclObjects.context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,cshape[level][0]*sizeof(float),bc[level]);


// SR using sub buffers only zeropad_buf and output_bf and to chunk up the buffer and submit the kernels twice...once to each device

//Creating sub_buffers for zeropad_buf

size_t zeropad_buf_size = (size+2)*(size+2)*cshape[level][1]*sizeof(float);
size_t output_buf_size = cshape[level][0]*size*size*sizeof(float);


size_t zeropad_split_pos = zeropad_buf_size / 2;
zeropad_split_pos -= zeropad_split_pos % total_alignment_requirement;
cl_buffer_region zero_rgn_4core = {0, zeropad_split_pos};
cl_buffer_region zero_rgn_2core = {zeropad_split_pos, zeropad_buf_size - zeropad_split_pos};


/*
cl_buffer_region zero_rgn_4core = {0, zeropad_buf_size/2};
cl_buffer_region zero_rgn_2core = {zeropad_buf_size/2, zeropad_buf_size/2};
*/


cl_buffer_region output_rgn_4core = {0, output_buf_size/2};
cl_buffer_region output_rgn_2core = {output_buf_size/2, output_buf_size/2};



cl::Buffer zeropad_buf_4Core = zeropad_buf.createSubBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &zero_rgn_4core);
std::cout<<"zero_pad sub-buffer region 1 created"<<std::endl;
cl::Buffer zeropad_buf_2Core = zeropad_buf.createSubBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &zero_rgn_2core); 
std::cout<<"zero_pad sub-buffer region 2 created"<<std::endl;

cl::Buffer output_buf_4Core = output_buf.createSubBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &output_rgn_4core);
cl::Buffer output_buf_2Core = output_buf.createSubBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &output_rgn_2core);

cl::NDRange global(global_x, global_y, global_y);
cl::NDRange local(1, group_size, group_size);   

//cl::Event evt[2];//SR

//SR use a vector events
std::vector<cl::Event> events;
cl::Event evt1, evt2;



//SR Kernel after sub buffering - 4 core
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(0, zeropad_buf_4Core);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(1, conv_weights[level]);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(2, output_buf_4Core);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(3, bs);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(4, size+2);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(5, cshape[level][1]);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(6, size);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(7, cshape[level][0]);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(8, CONV_SIZE);




cl_int err=openclObjects.queue[0].enqueueNDRangeKernel( openclObjects.conv_gpu, cl::NullRange, global, local, NULL, &evt1);  //SR
events.push_back(evt1);
```

//   cl_int err=openclObjects.queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel( openclObjects.conv_gpu, cl::NullRange, global, local, NULL)

```
//SR Kernel after sub buffering - 2 core
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(0, zeropad_buf_2Core);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(1, conv_weights[level]);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(2, output_buf_2Core);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<cl::Memory>(3, bs);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(4, size+2);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(5, cshape[level][1]);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(6, size);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(7, cshape[level][0]);
openclObjects.conv_gpu.setArg<int>(8, CONV_SIZE);


//SR Added for CQ2 (2 Core GPU)
err=openclObjects.queue[1].enqueueNDRangeKernel( openclObjects.conv_gpu, cl::NullRange, global, local, NULL, &evt2);
events.push_back(evt2);

std::cout<<"Enqueue CQ2"<<std::endl;

//get event info
cl::CommandQueue CQ;
cl::Device CQ_device;

evt2.getInfo(CL_EVENT_COMMAND_QUEUE,&CQ);


CQ.getInfo(CL_QUEUE_DEVICE, &CQ_device);

std::cout<<"New Code"<<std::endl;

std::cout<<"Event attached to COmmand Q2"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Device Name in Command Queue 1: "<<CQ_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Device Vendor: "<<CQ_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Device max CU: "<<CQ_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS>()<<std::endl;



cl::Event::waitForEvents(events);


//openclObjects.queue[0].finish(); //SR
std::cout<<"Command Queue 1 complete"<<std::endl;
//openclObjects.queue[1].finish();//SR added for CQ2
std::cout<<"Command Queue 2 complete"<<std::endl;
```

//      printf("global_x, global_y, global_y, error: %d %d %d %d\n",global_x, global_y, global_y, err);
//  printf("%d\n",err);

```
cl_ulong elapsed=0;

cl_ulong elapsed1=0; //SR calculate elapse per command queue
cl_ulong elapsed0=0; //SR calculate elapse per command queue

elapsed0 =evt1.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>()-evt1.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>(); //SR
std::cout<<"Profile Info: Command Queue 1"<<std::endl;

elapsed1 =evt2.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>()-evt2.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>(); //SR
std::cout<<"Profile Info: Command Queue 2"<<std::endl;

//std::cout<<"elapsed CQ0"<<elapsed0<<std::endl; //SR
//std::cout<<"elapsed CQ1"<<elapsed1<<std::endl; //SR

elapsed = elapsed0+elapsed1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uncomment openclObjects.queue[0].finish(); and openclObjects.queue[1].finish();

also u can use flush instead of finish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. The issue seem to persist only with the execution of the kernel with the second chunk of data. The event returns a -ve value.